# Jenkins pipeline multibranch issue reusing node type after parallel jobs

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-workflow, multibranch-pipeline

I'm attempting to migrate our CI process from JobDSL to a multibranch pipelines setup. As a first step I've decided to just have the pipeline delegate back to the existing jobs (passing the required params) My pipeline looks like below (pseudo code)

```
stage('setup')
node('cotroller') {
  ...
}


stage('test') {
  parallel {
    'web' : {build job 'web-test' ..params...},
    'API' : {build job 'api-test' ..params...}
  }
}

stage('build') { 
  parallel {
    'web' : {build job 'web-build' ..params...},
    'API' : {build job 'api-build' ..params...}
  }
}

stage('publish') {
  node('controller'){
    sh './gradlew publishArtifacts'
  }
}
```

However Im getting issues with the last 'publish' stage. When it kicks off the gradle target it correctly reused the workspace from the 'setup' phase, but seems to execute in a 'durable' sub folder from the original checkout (i.e the past in the setup phase execute in `/mnt/jenkins/workspace/<branchname>/<random_hash>/` however the last gradle target executes in a folder such as `/mnt/jenkins/workspace/<branchname>/<random_hash>@tmp/durable-<hash>/script.sh`) This is resulting in a gradlew not found error

I've tried playing around using the directory('/...'){...} but that doesnt seem to have resolved the issue...any help or guidance would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Saving setup path

You can try to save working directory from `setup` stage, e.g.:

```
stage('setup')
node('cotroller') {
  def setupPath = pwd()
  ...
}


stage('test') {
  parallel {
    'web' : {build job 'web-test' ..params...},
    'API' : {build job 'api-test' ..params...}
  }
}

stage('build') { 
  parallel {
    'web' : {build job 'web-build' ..params...},
    'API' : {build job 'api-build' ..params...}
  }
}

stage('publish') {
  node('controller'){
    dir("${setupPath}") {
      sh './gradlew publishArtifacts'
    }
  }
}
```

### Using Global Tool Configuration

The recommanded approach, according to [Jenkins pipeliens tutorial](https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-plugin/blob/master/TUTORIAL.md#setting-up), is to configure Gradle install path in the Jenkin's `Global Tool configuration`, name it anything (e.g. "`Gradle`") and then use it in your pipeline like this :

```
...

stage('publish') {
  node('controller'){
    def gradleHome = tool 'Gradle'        
    sh "${gradleHome}/bin/gradlew publishArtifacts'
  }
}
```

Comment: As we are using gradle wrapper, the relative paths should be fine, as the wrapper is within the rood directory of the git checkout.

Answer (score 0):

The groovy syntax didn't work for me. Had to change it to:

```
stage('test') {
    parallel (
        'web' : {build 'web-test' ..params...},
        'API' : {build 'api-test' ..params...}
    )
}
```